# SQL Server 2008 autocomplete for "TOP" keyword

Tags: sql-server-2008

Either the autocomplete in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 is buggy, or I am.  Either way, when I try to type this and hit the spacebar:

```
SELECT TOP
```

Autocomplete immediately changes it to this (**Topics** is a table in one of our databases, btw):

```
SELECT Topics
```

Is there a way to fix, or at least gracefully work around this?

Comment: I disable SSMS autocomplete years ago...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  SSMS Intellisense is a 1.0 product, and is not as feature-rich as many third-party products.  You can turn it off OR ignore the suggestion (with the ESC key).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for confirming this.  We just upgraded from SQL Server 2000, so this issue is an extremely minor gripe; I just wanted to know if it was a genuine bug.  I'll use ESC as a workaround until Microsoft patches it.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you can do is hit ESC when the intellisense pop-up appears which will cancel any change it makes, or just turn Intellisense off completely by going to Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> Intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered already but if you are looking for a tool that is quite useful/helpful try SQL Prompt from Red Gate. I have used this tool for years and found it is a great replacement for the built-in intellisense with plenty of options to allow for the tool help you be more efficient...

Comment: I use Devart dbForge SqlComplete Express, since it's free ( https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/editions.html ).  But yes, I agree with the sentiment -- I was forced to search out a third-party tool to get Intellisense to work normally again.

On the other end of the spectrum is JetBrains DataGrip, which aims to be a full-blown, cross-platform (Win/Mac/Linux) SQL IDE with support for many of the database heavyweights (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, DB2) and more.  https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can cheesily add one column empty tables for the most common keywords you have issues with.  Then it autocompletes to the table name but context puts it into the right usage.

Going one further you can:

```
CREATE table [top ] (c bit)
```

with the space at the end so the auto-complete is perfect.

After you create the object you'll want to hit `CTRL-SHFT-R` to refresh your Intellisense.

Comment: I work in an office with multiple database users with varying levels of SQL skills.  We just got Intellisense at the beginning of this year in this office.  Trying to train infrequent users about the esc key can be...trying.