# SQL Server 2008 Intellisense - Typing 'top' brings up tables, causes confusion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, intellisense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server 2008 autocomplete for "TOP" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569010/sql-server-2008-autocomplete-for-top-keyword)

SQL Server 2008 introduced Intellisense while writing queries. Problem is, whenever I type in "SELECT TOP" and press space, it replaces TOP with a table named 'Top3_Animations'...

Is there a way to add "TOP" to the Intellisense list?  Or to fix this some other way?

Comment: +1 For the confusion badge :)  I solved this by turning intellisense off, but hoping someone posts a better way!

Comment: Press escape before space? That has helped me.